# questionnaire with feedback redirect based on score

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to add to my site a simple questionnaire with few multiple choice questions. Each question has a score and at the end tha user is redirected to a custom page based on overall score. 
Can somebody recommend me such php or javascript script or any other possible solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, you are not supposed to ask people to give you a code in this site. You should try to make your own first, and if you get any problems then ask for help. But, as far as your a php script for questions, then here is a an entire source code, from elanman.

http://blog.elanman.com/elanzips/php-quiz.zip

You also have the famous hotscripts, check it out here:

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/tests-quizzes/

Comment: Hello, I checked hotscripts and will check out elanmann's scripts too. Thank you